# Docker container not starting after rebuilding

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a project where I start all the services needed using what is essentially a [`docker-compose` script](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/provotum-v2/blob/3061a8e9e35730cd256a9f3347d0d8ed3cadcd67/docker-prebuilt-up.sh#L24). This `docker-compose` command uses a [YAML file](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/provotum-v2/blob/prebuilt/pre-built.yml). Everything starts correctly by default. This includes the voter frontend I'm having trouble with later on:

```
$ docker ps | grep voter
9e6f8148bfb6   docker.pkg.github.com/alexscheitlin/master-project-evoting/voter_frontend:v2
```

But when I create a voter frontend image using [this script](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/provotum-v2/blob/2a3f09152087ed6364a894c7f1ec6343957a0f93/voter-frontend/docker-build.sh) using the same code that created the original image, it doesn't start when I [replace it](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/provotum-v2/blob/2a3f09152087ed6364a894c7f1ec6343957a0f93/pre-built.yml#L123) in the YAML file (`docker ps | grep voter` produces no result unlike before). Why is this the case?

Also, running the default image (docker.pkg.github.com/alexscheitlin/master-project-evoting/voter_frontend:v2) yields:

```
$ docker run docker.pkg.github.com/alexscheitlin/master-project-evoting/voter_frontend:v2
ERROR: Unknown or unexpected option: -d -s build -l tcp://172.1.1.30:3000
```

And running my modified one yields:

```
$ docker run ghcr.io/kevin-mok/voter_frontend:text
file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/build/main.js:169
      const ipAddress = request.socket.remoteAddress?.replace("::ffff:", "") ?? "unknown";
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:140:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

That is to say, I don't know how to run either with just `docker run`.

You can run my code by cloning [my repository](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/provotum-v2), checking out the `prebuilt` branch and running `./docker-prebuilt-up.sh` after [setting up the prerequisites](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/provotum-v2/tree/prebuilt#prerequisites).